# What is current state of iOS support of Rust?

Tags: ios, rust

[This document](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/wiki/Doc-building-for-ios) is saying the safe tasks are not supported on iOS target due to lack of segmented stack support. I looked into Rust's issue tracker, and this is somewhat related to thread-local-storage of 32-bit version of iOS. Well, I am not really familiar with this kind of topics.

Anyway, [this text](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/rust-dev/2013-November/006314.html) is saying the segmented stack approach is going to be abandoned. There's [an HN entry](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6679918) which says it's not really required in 64-bit systems.

I am confusing on this. What is current state of iOS support of Rust? No stack protection at all on tasks? Or protected only in 64-bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [blog post](http://vhbit.net/blog/2015/01/18/rust-for-ios-status-update/) that claims

> Rust is now completely ported to iOS: all architectures for device/simulator are supported. Since green threads were removed, adding support of arm64 was actually almost straightforward.

Github also has [an example iOS app](https://github.com/drewcrawford/Rust-iOS-Example) (written in Swift) that calls into a cross-compiled framework (written in Rust).

Comment: Here is another post: https://jakerr.github.io/rust/ios/2015/04/02/experimenting-with-rust-ios.html

Answer (score 2):

Segmented stacks were abandoned, and there have been lots of 'fix iOS build' PRS: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?q=ios&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93

I don't know more than that, though.

Answer (score 1):

iOS target (both `armv7` and `aarch64`) is officially supported as [a Tier 2 platform](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html).

> Tier 2 platforms can be thought of as "guaranteed to build". Automated tests are not run so it's not guaranteed to produce a working build, but platforms often work to quite a good degree and patches are always welcome!

Mac->iOS cross compiler is [automatically built](https://buildbot.rust-lang.org/builders/auto-mac-cross-ios-opt) on every PR/merge.

The team is [happy to improve support](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/suggestion-make-real-world-tier-1-platforms-at-least-tier-2/3492/14?u=kornel). It's mostly a matter of somebody making a reliable buildbot integration for automated tests.